# Как сохранить HTML-разметку в текстовый файл? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ниже приведён пример кода.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Banner extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


       this.renderImg = this.renderImg.bind(this);
    }
    

    renderImg () {
            return (
                <div key={this.props.id} className="storie" >
                    <img src={this.props.src} />
                    <span>{this.props.text}</span>
                </div>
            );
    }
    render () {
       
        return (
            <div className="flex">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-10 m-5 banner">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            {this.renderImg()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            
        );
    }


}


export default Banner;
```

Могу ли я сохранить в текстовый файл результат вывода функции `renderImg`? Мне нужен именно **html-код, который был отрендерен** в браузере. Как это сделать на React?

Comment: С помощью `document.querySelector('html')` получить html и отправить на сервер, чтобы тот сохранил файл

Comment: Ну что в конечном счете получилось в браузере без самого браузера вы вряд ли узнаете, но если очень хочется увидеть какой-то результат рендеринга, то можно воспользоваться например `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вот такой пример, который подошел мне:

```
nodeToString ( node ) {
        var tmpNode = document.createElement( "div" );
        tmpNode.appendChild( node.cloneNode( true ) );
        var str = tmpNode.innerHTML;
        tmpNode = node = null; // prevent memory leaks in IE
        return str;
    }
```